# SockJS on IE9 - getting ERROR - Incompatibile SockJS! Main site uses: "1.0.3", the iframe: "1.0.0"

Tags: spring, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am using SockJS 1.0.3 for websocket with fallback support. Using Spring Websocket API with SockJS on the server side.

Everything seems to be working fine except when I try and connect using IE9. As the browser tries to connect to the URL, following message is displayed on the console

```
Incompatibile SockJS! Main site uses: "1.0.3", the iframe: "1.0.0"
```

After throwing this message, the connection gets established, however, after approx. 60 seconds the connection gets closed automatically. I don't get such behavior on any other browser (Mozilla / Chrome / IE11).

Anyone having any clue on what's going on actually.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved finally. Resolution was in the error message, so changed the SockJS version from 1.0.3 to 1.0.0

Now, don't see the "Incompatible SockJS Message" on console and the connection too is not closed automatically.